# Change Shown Decimal Places in Plot

Tags: plotting

I want my Y axis to be precise to 2 decimal places, I've tried:

```
    Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[lm[x], {x, 0.00, 25.00}], 
     AxesLabel -> {"Volume (mL)", "Mass (g)"}, 
     PlotLabel -> lm["Mass vs. Volume of Various Volumetric Pipets"], 
     PlotRange -> {{0.00, 25.00}, {0.00, 25.00}}, 
     BaseStyle -> {PrintPrecision -> 4}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
     GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dotted, Orange]]
```

And the output is not what I am wanting:
[image]
I've tried the `FrameTicks->{}` function and that didn't change my output either. I'm used to R so I really don't know where to go with this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

"13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"

Clear["Global`*"]

plt = Plot[x, {x, 0, 25}];
```

Modify the existing [`Ticks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html),

```
Show[plt,
 Ticks -> {Automatic, (Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[plt, Ticks])[[2]] /.
    {y_, lbl_String?(StringLength[#] > 0 &), rest_} :>
     {y, NumberForm[y, {5, 2}], rest}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
plt = Plot[x, {x, 0, 25}
  , Ticks -> {
    Automatic,
    {#, DecimalForm[1.0 #, {6, 2}]} & /@ Range[0, 25, 5]
    }
  ]
```